# How do I check if two strings are equal in Java when either one of the strings can be a null?

Tags: java

I have two strings ...

```
String s1 = /* any string, could be null */;
String s2 = /* any string, could be null */;
```

I need to know if they are equal.

I can't do `s1.equals(s2)` because NullPointer if `s1 == null`.

Is this the best way to check if they are equal?

```
public boolean stringsAreEqual(String s1, String s2) {
    boolean bEqual = false;
    if ((s1 == null) && (s2 == null)) {
        bEqual = true;
    } else if ((s1 != null) && s1.equals(s2)) {
        bEqual = true;
    } else if ((s2 != null) && s2.equals(s1)) {
        bEqual = true;
    }  
    return bEqual;
}
```

Comment: @Swati Don't recommend third party libs please.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not need to create a new method for that. You can use `java.util.Objects#equals(Object a, Object b)` from the Java standard library. Below is the definition as on JDK.

```
public static boolean equals(Object a, Object b) {
    return (a == b) || (a != null && a.equals(b));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare strings like this.
This is what Java internal code uses.

```
public boolean stringsAreEqual(String s1, String s2) {
    return (s1 == null ? s2 == null : s1.equals(s2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A==null ? B==null : A.equals(B)

Comment: Please add more information or explanation to justify the answer.

Comment: Less "readable" than I normally would write, but this is a nice concise solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you could first make the method `static`, and second test if `s1` is `null`, if it is test `s2` for null. Otherwise compare `s1` and `s2`. Like,

```
public static boolean stringsAreEqual(String s1, String s2) {
    if (s1 == null) {
        return s2 == null;
    }
    return s1.equals(s2);
}
```